# Импорт в csv по колонкам

Tags: php, csv

Можно ли импортировать в файл csv не построчно, а колонками? Сейчас получается так, а нужно, чтобы каждое значение в своей колонке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  if (CModule::IncludeModule('catalog')){

    // открываем файл для записи
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'ExportSuccess.csv';
    $fp = fopen("ExportSuccess.csv", 'w');
    $arName = array("АРТИКУЛ","  ","НАЗВАНИЕ","  ","АКТИВНОСТЬ","  ","КОЛИЧЕСТВО","  ","ЦЕНА","  ","ДАТА ОБНОВЛЕНИЯ");

    // Добавляем 3х байтную последовательность для кодировки UTF-8
    fwrite($fp, "\xEF\xBB\xBF");  
    fputcsv($fp, $arName, " ", " ");

    // Выбираем измененые экспортом сегодня
    $arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "ACTIVE", "DETAIL_PICTURE","IBLOCK_ID","PROPERTY_*");
    $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>8, "MODIFIED_USER_ID" => 3, "DATE_MODIFY_FROM" => $date);
    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>5), $arSelect);
    while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
    {
        $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
        $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
        $ar_res = CCatalogProduct::GetByID($arFields["ID"]);
        $arPrice = CPrice::GetByID($arFields["ID"]);

        $artnumber = $arFields["PROPERTY_291"]; // артикул
        $name = $arFields["NAME"]; // имя
        $active = $arFields["ACTIVE"]; // активность
        $quantity = $ar_res["QUANTITY"]; // количество
        $price = $arPrice["PRICE"]; // цена

        // изображение
        if (empty($arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"]))
            {
                $picture = "Есть"; 
            } 
        else 
            {
                $picture = "Нет изображения";
            }

        $date_modify = $arFields["TIMESTAMP_X"]; // дата обновления
        $name =  str_replace("&quot", "",  $arFields["NAME"]);
        // формируем результирующий массив
        $arRes = array ($artnumber,"  ",$name,"  ", $active,"  ", $quantity,"  ",$price, "  ",$picture,"  ",$date_modify);
        fputcsv($fp, $arRes, " ", " ");      
        //     echo "<pre>";
        //     print_r($artnumber);
        // //    print_r($arProps);
        //     echo "</pre>";
    }

    echo "success!";
    fclose($fp);
  }
```

Comment: как я вижу вы записываете целую стоку в одну ячейку, формат файла построчный, а данные разделены символом `;`. Все что вам нужно, это заменить пробелы (если я правильно понимаю структуру файла) на точку с запятой. Покажите код который получился в `.csv` и то, как именно вы преобразовываете в данный формат данные

Comment: согласен с Василием покажите код, с помощью которого формируете csv

Comment: Скорее всего, там не пробелы, а табуляция -- и этот файл нужно просто открыть, например, в OpenOffice Calc.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев @Naumov Добавил код в задачу. Я так понимаю, нужно `fputcsv($fp, $arRes, " ", " ");  ` здесь заменить разделители?

Comment: @Николай все правильно, `fputcsv($fp, $arRes, ";")` Тебе нужно разделять не пробелом, а точкой с запятой. 4й параметр не обязательный, задает символ экранирования. Спецификация: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fputcsv.php